# .htaccess filename to url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been searching and cannot find an answer that suits my needs. It is a rather simple question I assume.

The point is that I need to rewrite my files to a name of my liking. For example I have, 'www.mydomain.com/account_index.php' which I want to rewrite to www.mydomain.com/account

Thus far I had this, but that doesn't seem to work with multiple lines.

```
Rewriteengine on
rewriterule ^support account_ticket.php [L]
rewriterule ^account account_index.php [L]
```

So in short, I want my website to redirect /account to account_index.php and the other way around.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: RewriteRule ^support$ Path/your_php_file_name.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer for those that are wondering.
I had to put a `RewriteCond` before every `RewriteRule`.

So if I wanted to go to www.mydomain.com/account. I'd have this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/account$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^account account_index.php [NC,L]
```

This means that /account is now linked to account_index.php.

Have a nice day!